# Convert values in list between 0 to 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, numbers

I have a list of integer ranging from -3 to 3.

```
list = [-0.33, -2.5, 2.1, ......., -1.2, -2.4444, 1.788]
```

Is there a way to convert all the numbers between 0 to 1?

Comment: Assuming your list is `data`, use `lo, hi = min(data), max(data); print ([(i - lo) / (hi-lo) for i in data])`. Don't have to get fancy with `numpy` or `sklearn`.

Comment: This question explicitly states the input range to be -3 to 3. The claim that it is a duplicate, @Henry’s comment, and @Divyessh’s answer are all incorrect as they normalize to a range of it’s min and max values. Based on the wording of the question, this is not what is being asked.

Comment: OP is asking `Is there a way to convert all the numbers between 0 to 1`. I don't see how it is incorrect to normalize it @Liam.

Comment: @HenryYik I interpret “ranging from -3 to 3” to mean “map a range of (-3 to 3) to a range of (0 to 1). I think that’s the most reasonable interpretation and I doubt OP would have mentioned the range of the input unless this is what was intended. Can you please clarify, @Chris_007?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
>>> data = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
>>> scaler = StandardScaler()
>>> print(scaler.fit(data))
StandardScaler()
>>> print(scaler.mean_)
[0.5 0.5]
>>> print(scaler.transform(data))
```

this shall convert the data into -1 to 1

Answer (score -1):

Add three to each, then divide by six.

```py
lst = [-0.33, -2.5, 2.1, ......., -1.2, -2.4444, 1.788]
lst = [(i + 3) / 6 for i in lst]
```

(I renamed `list` to `lst`, as the former conflicts with the preexisting `list` type)